# Is it ok to omit the text version of an email when it's just an "alert" notification?

Tags: email, smtp

Is it alright to send HTML-only emails without the text/plain part when doing HTML only actions like clicking a link to view replies or some other "alert" type notification? For example, clicking a link to activate your email or clicking to see new comments.

```
Date: Wed, 07 Mar 2012 10:30:54 -0800 (PST)
From: email@site.com
Subject: Test Mail
To: <email@site.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

VGhpcyBpcyBdfJDFKdjfkdsFpbCBmcm9tIGxvY2FsaG9zdCB3aXRoIGZzbdrb3BlbigpIGF0IDEz
eGVvbmNyb3NzLmNvbSI+eGVvbmNyb3NzLmNvbTwvYT4gPGk+bGluazwvaT4hPHA+VGhpcyBpcyBt
b3JlIHRleHQ8L3A+
```

Instead of using multipart to create two copies of the same email.

```
Date: Wed, 07 Mar 2012 10:30:54 -0800 (PST)
From: email@site.com
Subject: Test Mail
To: <email@site.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="4f57a7d259baf"

--4f57a7d259baf
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

VGhpcyBpcyBdfJDFKdjfkdsFpbCBmcm9tIGxvY2FsaG9zdCB3aXRoIGZzbdrb3BlbigpIGF0IDEz
eGVvbmNyb3NzLmNvbSI+eGVvbmNyb3NzLmNvbTwvYT4gPGk+bGluazwvaT4hPHA+VGhpcyBpcyBt
b3JlIHRleHQ8L3A+

--4f57a7d259baf
Content-Type: text/text; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

VGhpcyBpcyBdfJDFKdjfkdsFpbCBmcm9tIGxvY2FsaG9zdCB3aXRoIGZzbdrb3BlbigpIGF0IDEz
MzExNDQ2NTgKCkFsc28gd2l0aCBhIGdvb2dsZS5jb20gdXJsIGFuZCB4ZW9uY3Jvc3MuY29tIGxp
bmshVGhpcyBpcyBtb3JlIHRleHQ=
```

I would like to save the bandwidth if there isn't a very good reason to include the text version.

Comment: Just how many of these emails do you expect to be sending if the ~300bytes of overhead for html breaks your budget? Or in other words, just how expensive is your bandwidth?

Comment: How about omitting the HTML portion if you *really* want to save bandwidth? As a bonus your alert email would be readable on any device.

Comment: @MarcB, my emails are longer than the three-line samples above. Johnsyweb, the whole point of the emails is to provide a fast way to click-through to something. I don't care about alerting them if there is no way to respond.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: But then it wouldn't be clickable. =P

Comment: Many popular mail clients will render URIs as "clickable" links in plain text emails. Some terminals will do this too, even if the mail client is `mutt`.

Comment: Depends a lot on your target audience. If your users are Unix admins, I don't think HTML-only will fly. If they're salespeople, they won't notice the difference, and/or request the email in XLS format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to save bandwidth, I don't think you should be using base64 encoding as it makes your data 33% larger (on average). In my understanding, `text/plain` (not `text/text`) should always be provided in a human-readable format (like quoted-printable).

I don't think there are many e-mail clients that can't read HTML nowadays, still I think your decision should reflect how important it is for the end-user to be able to read (and understand) your e-mail / alert and not (minor) bandwidth limitations. I've no experience with AOL, but I think it had some issues with e-mail links a few years ago, perhaps that counts as a bonus points for the plain text alternative.

Also, don't forget that the actual links need to be displayed in plain text versions.